# shm_open and ftruncate() in Shared Memory Programming

Tags: c, linux

I want to create a Shared Memory Object and truncate it to a specific size.

SHMSIZE is defined with 512

MODE is set with S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IWOTH | S_IROTH

Here is my Code

```c
char *shm_name = "SharedMemory";    
int fd; 

/* Open an Shared Memory Object for Read-/Write-Access */    
if((fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, MODE) < 0)) {     
     perror("\nshm_open() in Caretaker failed");    
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Truncate Shared Memory Object to specific size */
if((ftruncate(fd, SHMSIZE) < 0)) {
    perror("\nftruncate() in Caretaker failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

While Debugging i watched that the return value of shm_open() is 0 every time, but i can see this object in /dev/shm. And while executing ftruncate() it returns every time with error "invalid argument".

Why fd is 0 every time and why ftruncate doesn't work?
What should i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of operations in this statement is wonky:

```
if((fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, MODE) < 0)) {
```

You're assigning the result of `shm_open(...) < 0` to `fd`, which is definitely not what you want.

Move the comparison outside the parentheses:

```
if((fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, MODE)) < 0) {
                                                   ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometime it's such a simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try by first declaring fd then comparing it to 0.

```
    int fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, MODE);
    if (fd < 0){
       perror("\nshm_open() in Caretaker failed");
    }
```

It brings about less confusion after all.