# C Linux shared memory error - ftruncate

Tags: c, memory, shared

I'm trying to open a shared mem file and write into it. The problem is that ftruncate is returning -1 .

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void) {


    int fd;
    fd=shm_open("/shmem-m", O_CREAT,0777);
    printf("%d\n",fd);
    int a=ftruncate(fd, 1024);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    void* addr=mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd, 0);
    char* msg= "hola mundo!";
    memcpy(addr,msg,strlen(msg));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    //return 0;


}
```

The output is:

```
3
-1
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: When system calls like [`ftruncate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) returns `-1` it means there is an error, you should check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what's wrong. You can use e.g. [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print an error message.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320359/shm-open-and-ftruncate-in-shared-memory-programming

Comment: Try `shm_open("/shmem-m", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)`. The file must be opened in write mode to use `ftruncate`.

Comment: Thank you! using fd=shm_open("/shmem-m",  O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that POSIX requires the file to be opened in write mode for a call to `ftruncate` to succeed as stated in the [ftruncate man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate).

So the call to `shm_open` becomes `shm_open("/shmem-m", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)`, with the `O_RDWR` flag set ([shm_open man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open)).